# XSLT: move specific elements into new parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an problem moving specific elements from a collection into a new parent node. I know how to select these elements (here: root/order/person[position() > 1] for msxml) but can´t figure out the correct usage of xslt:copy or xslt:copy-of statements.

This is what i have (for example):

```
<root>
  <order>
    <person>
      ...
    </person>
    <person>
       ...
    </person>
    <person>
       ...
    </person>
  </order>
</root>
```

And I just want to put the person elements (1-n) each into a single order element:

```
<root>
  <order>
    <person>
      ...
    </person>
  </order>
  <order>
    <person>
      ...
    </person>
  </order>
  <order>
    <person>
      ...
    </person>
  </order>
</root>
```

I already achieved to delete the person elements except the first one from the order element. But now I am having trouble moving the remaining person elements into newly created order elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how to select these elements (here:
> root/order/person[position() > 1] for msxml)
>
> ...
>
> And I just want to put the person elements (1-n) each into a single
> order element:

Either I am missing something here or you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="order/person">
            <order>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </order>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- skip order wrapper -->
<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- add order wrapper to each person -->
<xsl:template match="person">
    <order>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </order>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to override the identity template (read up on how to do that). This makes the copying of input tree the default behaviour except for the bits you override.

```
<!-- import the identity template -->
<xsl:import href="identity.xsl"/>

<!-- this removes the original order element that wrapped the persons -->
<xsl:template match="order">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- this creates an order element around each person. -->
<xsl:template match="person">
  <order>
    <!-- Because of the identity template override the old person element gets copied here -->
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
  </order>
</xsl:template>
```